# HTMLEditorExtender width cannot fit %100

Tags: width, htmleditorextender

Using ajaxcontroltoolkit.as my horror film.

HTMLEditorExtender stays its prerendered width as it is even if I resize the Web Browser

it doesnt detect width resizements:Stays as how it is.

and need a full refresh of browser (F5) makes HTMLEditorExtender to re calcluate its width.

so.

is there a standart way to fix this problem ? otherwise I will use jquery to slap it.or remove this horror control.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbEditor" runat="server"
            TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" style="width:100%">
</asp:TextBox>
        <asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="tbEditor_HtmlEditorExtender" runat="server" 
            Enabled="True" TargetControlID="tbEditor">
        </asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a css rule

```
.containerClass .ajax__html_editor_extender_container
        {
            width: 100% !important;/*important is really important at here*/
        }
```

and a surrounding div, fixed problem.

```
<div class="containerClass">
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbEditor" runat="server"
            TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" style="width:100%">
</asp:TextBox>
        <asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="tbEditor_HtmlEditorExtender" runat="server" 
            Enabled="True" TargetControlID="tbEditor">
        </asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
        </div>
```

fixed my problem.hope this helps someone too.